# How to check if user entered bad html

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a page in which I have a textarea in which user can enter HTML, and a preview button where user can view the html entered by him.

I want to track whether the html entered by him is valid or not. I will give a message if it is invalid

Answer (score 2):

Load the posted HTML into the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) - it is an HTML parser.

The `ParseErrors` collection will be empty if the HTML was valid.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [h5Validate](http://ericleads.com/h5validate/)

> Best practice realtime HTML5 form validation for jQuery. Works on all popular browsers, including old ones like IE6.
>   ◦ Regularly tested on 13 different browsers, IE6 - IE9, FireFox, Chrome, iPhone, and Android.
>   ◦ Implements best practices based on 1,000 user survey, several usability studies, and the behavior of millions of users in live production environments.